# iPhone: Container View Controller and Camera Preview: preview is not displayed in child view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, camera, avfoundation, uistoryboard

I have found and read this [tutorial](http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1273). It is very good indeed! I use the word 'read' on purpose. If I had understood, I would not be asking here now.

Now: I tried to plug what I have read into my application. I need different overlays with controls for the still image and the camera preview. I need the camera preview to sit still while the rest of the application rotates. I need it to be AVFoundation, because there will be a lot of additional image and camera functionality. I want to rotate all of the application BUT the camera preview. A self-made container view controller is to be the hinge point. Outside of it, the application rotates. It controls rotation for its children and I hope to be able to reduce my manual rotation to the overlay of the camera preview child view controller of said container view controller.

(Aside: on top of it all I am using linked storyboards, ARC and CoreData (later for the photos))

Point is: I have this view controller in a container view controllers container view. That is the one I want the preview to be in. I want the still image in another of the container view controllers child view controllers and a third child is to be a browser for fotos. Later there will be buttons and gestures to navigate from one child to the other. The capture session manager is a property of the container view controller, i.e. the parent.

I have set up all the @properties (in the capture session manager, the container view controller and the camera preview view controller) in a way that they will be created when they are not already there. I have given the camera preview view controller a property that is a capture session manager but is supposed to only be a pointer to the parents session manager (laziness or fatal error?).

As far as I can tell, stepping thru with the debugger, the connection has been made. Now, in the viewDidLoad method of the camera preview view controller, I try to display the preview layer.

And then I see...  ...nothing but a blank white view :(

What could I have forgotten?

At this point the parent-child connection should have been made. The embed segue sets the capture manager of the child:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"EmbedCameraPreview"])
    { // present destination view
        if ([[segue destinationViewController] isKindOfClass:[CameraPreviewViewController class]]) {
            CameraPreviewViewController * destinationVC = (CameraPreviewViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];            
            [destinationVC setCaptureManager:[self captureManager]];
        }
        [self addChildView:[segue destinationViewController]];
    }
}

- (void) addChildView: (UIViewController*) content {
    [self addChildViewController:content];
    content.view.frame = [self maxFrame]; 
    [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}

- (CGRect) maxFrame {
    return [[[self view] layer] bounds];
}
```

The capture manager of the child is private (in the .m-file), with a public setter:

Interface:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) CaptureSessionManager *captureManager;
```

Implementation:

```
@synthesize captureManager;

- (void)setCaptureManager:(CaptureSessionManager *) newCaptureManager {
    if (captureManager != newCaptureManager) {
        captureManager = newCaptureManager;
    }
}

- (CaptureSessionManager *) captureManager {
    if (captureManager != nil) {
        return captureManager;
    }

    if ([[self parentViewController] isKindOfClass:[CameraContainerViewController class]]) {
        CameraContainerViewController* parentView = (CameraContainerViewController*)[self parentViewController];        
        [self setCaptureManager:[parentView captureManager]];
    }

    return captureManager;
}
```

`viewDidLoad` of the child is called from `content.view.frame = [self maxFrame]` inside `addChildView` of the parent (see above: the `prepareForSegue`):

```
- (void) displayCameraPreview
{
    CGRect layerRect = [[[self view] layer] bounds];
    [[[self captureManager] previewLayer] setBounds:layerRect];
    [[[self captureManager] previewLayer] setPosition:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(layerRect),
                                                                  CGRectGetMidY(layerRect))];
    [[[self view] layer] addSublayer:[[self captureManager] previewLayer]];
}

- (void) initDisplay {    
    [self displayCameraPreview];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self initDisplay];
}
```

Help, please? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am SO VERY SORRY!

Thank you again to the author of the above mentioned tutorial. Great job!

I have overlooked a tiny detail when ripping the code apart to set to different view controllers. One should START the session, shouldn't one? Here is the source that will work:

```
- (void) displayCameraPreview
{
    CGRect layerRect = [[[self view] layer] bounds];
    [[[self captureManager] previewLayer] setBounds:layerRect];
    [[[self captureManager] previewLayer] setPosition:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(layerRect),
                                                                  CGRectGetMidY(layerRect))];
    [[[self view] layer] addSublayer:[[self captureManager] previewLayer]];

    [[captureManager captureSession] startRunning];
}
```